# C++ DLL does not run on different machine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I am developing a simple c++ application to generate a dll which later I am using in JNI to run native api calls, but the thing is the dll works well on the machine which I used to develop the dll but does not on the server. Both machines run Windows 7.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: de.deltacontrols.enteliprint.printer.
PrinterService.getStatus(Ljava/lang/String;)I

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: I added the error to the question

Comment: [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/) means that it does not find the dll!? maybe check if the dll can be found? and is on the right path?

Comment: thanks, there was a miss match of codes between c++ code and java interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On machine it doesnt work open your dll in [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Examine the out put for errors, it is possible that you are using debug version of your dll which works fine on machine with visual studio or it maybe c++ redistributable which is missing on target machine

Comment: I changed the compile mode from debug to release, but still I have the error, I edited the question and added the error

Comment: One more thing that I was thinking about is that the visual studio I have is provided by my University, I am not sure exactly, maybe it is a limited version

Comment: dependency walker says: Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Comment: warnings for delay-loaded are ok. did you open the dll in dependency walker on the target machine?

Comment: yes, here is the snapshot
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-OrX916ffOQZC01STQta2JjeFk&authuser=0

Comment: just curious, what is it?

Comment: on my local machine the dll which I built early 2 months ago was on debug mode and did not work out on remote one, then when I changed the debug to release today to test it on release, I forgot that I did modifications on interface of c++ code :) hence the error was thrown, but I was inattentive to that particular error, because the previous one which was on debug mode build was different